# Giving me Error: page 404 not found

Tags: 404, page

Whe i try to enter some configurations in magento backend i get strange 404 error page.

[image]

I am running Nginx server so htaccess has nothing to do with this.
Anyone had this issue? Any help would be very appreciated.

I'm entering sales->orders and any order. This error appears also in multiple module configuration pages.

I'v noticed that something is wrong with stores. Because when i created new store and set it as default. Now every page gives me the same error. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Add more details, like logs and what are you entering where?

Comment: I'm entering sales->orders and some order. System logs are empty so are nginx error logs.

Comment: Did you try to add / remove `/index.php/` to your URL ?

Comment: Tried it now. Didn't make any difference.

Comment: Are you sure that the admin URL key is the same as in `/etc/local.xml` in XML path `admin/routers/adminhtml/args/frontName` ?

Comment: Yes i'm sure.
`<routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>`. Like i said it happens not in all backend pages.

Comment: I'v noticed that something is wrong with Stores. Because when i created new store. And set as default. Now every page gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, in nginx config, where is located the php location, you muat pass the store code id eg "default".

The variable is

MAGE_RUN_CODE and MAGE_RUN_TYPE

Something like

fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;

Comment: Well didn't fix the error. Thanks for reply. I'm thinking about reinstalling magento from scratch. Because there is something very wrong with stores.

Comment: @90sKid paste here the nginx config specially the php location

Comment: location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
        #
        #       # With php5-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }`

Comment: @90sKid see, you miss those parameters fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store; fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;   also what is your store code?

Comment: That part gives me 404 page on every page.

Comment: @90sKid yes you need to specify EXACTLY the store code in mage_run_code you can look at phpymadmin and core_stores

Comment: I see 2 stores (in magento i see only one). When i change store code in nginx to my main store i get same result as it is now. 404 appears on some pages but not all.

Comment: So you have 2 domains / url once for each store? If yes you need to look at nignx map function, where you declare that for domain eg domain1.com corresponds mage_run_code dom1

Comment: Nope. I have only one domain. And using only one store. I have no idea why there is 2 stores in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Very odd then i'm using this config on hundreds of servers with no issue at all..

Comment: Yes that is very odd. Something is very wrong here. Because when i delete the first store that i don't need. I start to get 404 on every page.. Well i think i should try reinstalling. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @90sKid ok. No problem!